# How to implement a list environment for simple proofs?

Tags: macros, environments, logic

I'm trying to learn LaTeX macro writing, so I'm creating a list-like environment to typeset proofs (introductory propositional logic). I've been able to get a decent looking result this way:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{r c l}
    1. & $some math$ & Justification.\\
    2. & $some math$ & Justification.\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Although this looks alright, there are a few problems with it: numbering is manual and isn't recalculated when I organize it, the structure is very repetitive, and it's not obvious what it's supposed to be (to my eye).

I'd like to create an environment with this kind of syntax:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
    \step some math & Justification.
    \step some math & Justification.
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

What's the best way to accomplish this (if it's at all possible)?

**EDIT:** Just to clarify, I know enough to do automatic numbering in a table and so on. What I really need help with is getting the text after the `\step` command into a macro/environment.

Comment: I would use paracol.  You just have to figure out how wide to make the respective columns ahead of time.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I think I can figure that out. My main problem is getting everything after the `\step` command into an environment. I can figure out the rest (using `\stepcounter` etc). I'll edit my question to clarify.

Comment: I would look at the LaTeX for Logicians website and see if somebody has already created an environment of the kind you need - or one close to it, which you could tweak appropriately. Unless this is just an educational exercise and you don't actually need to use this for anything in the real world.

Comment: http://www.logicmatters.net/latex-for-logicians/ - guessing you probably want one of the natural deduction proof packages, but that's just a guess.

Comment: Note that you should not create a new environment `proof` as the name is already used (by `amsmath`, if not the core format).

Comment: Another approach: You could collect the whole environment body (using `environ`) and then split that at the `\step` token. Afterwards you map through the split list and typeset it accordingly (e.g. by passing the rest of the line to an internal step macro).

Comment: @cfr Good to know. I was planning on doing something like "simproof" to get around that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, I wound up using 3 columns.  That allows me the fit display math inside the boundaries.  The macros `\step` and `\reason` are defined only inside the proof environment.  Note that I redefined `\theequation` in the rightmost column to include the step number.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[leqno]{amsmath}
\usepackage{paracol}
\setcolumnwidth{\labelwidth,4cm}

\newcounter{step}
\globalcounter{step}

\newenvironment{proof}{\setcounter{step}{0}%
  \parindent=0pt
  \sloppy
  \def\step{\switchcolumn[0]*[\medskip]%
    \refstepcounter{step}%
    \makebox[\columnwidth][r]{\textbf{\thestep.}}%
    \switchcolumn[1]}%
  \def\reason{\switchcolumn[2]
    \setcounter{equation}{0}%
    \renewcommand{\theequation}{\thestep.\arabic{equation}}}%
  \paracol{3}}%
 {\endparacol}
\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
\step some math \reason This shows what happens when text extends beyond one line.

\step This shows what happens when text extends beyond one line.
\begin{equation}x = a\end{equation}
\reason justification
\begin{equation}a = x\end{equation}

\step some math \reason justification
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Wow. This is more robust than the solution I had in mind. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap a `tabular` in a `proof` environment where `\step` translates to setting a number and a column separator `&`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcounter{proofstep}
\newcommand{\step}{}
\newenvironment{proofA}
  {\par
   \setcounter{proofstep}{0}%
   \renewcommand{\step}{\refstepcounter{proofstep}\theproofstep. &}%
   \noindent
   \begin{tabular}{ @{} r c l @{}}}
  {\end{tabular}}
\newenvironment{proofB}
  {\par
   \setcounter{proofstep}{0}%
   \renewcommand{\step}{\refstepcounter{proofstep}\theproofstep. &}%
   \noindent
   \tabularx{\textwidth}{ @{} r c X @{} }}
  {\endtabularx}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{ @{} r c l @{} }
  1. & some math & Justification. \\
  2. & some math & Justification.
\end{tabular}

\begin{proofA}
  \step some math & Justification. \\
  \step some math & Justification.
\end{proofA}

\begin{proofB}
  \step some math & This is just another sentence that will span at least two lines. Well, now it will, for sure! \\
  \step some math & Justification.
\end{proofB}

\end{document}
```

Two proof environments are provided: `proofA` and `proofB`. The first uses a regular `tabular`, the second uses a `tabularx` that allows for justified paragraph text.

Comment: This is along the lines of what I was thinking, but John's answer looks more versatile. Thank you for your suggestion though!

Comment: @Sircular17: Well yes, of course. Using a `tabular` for this type of description could be problematic when the environment occurs around a page break - `tabular`s don't break naturally.