# Rules of Inference aligning on latex document

Tags: tables, alignment, logic, logicproof

Hi I'm trying to write a neat step by step description of rules of inference just like the picture below

It seems like there are 3 columns and on each column it is center aligned.

Is this form just using tables without lines?? If there is anyone who has experience writing a document on propositional logic pls give out some tips. Thanks

[image: The latex I want to make]

Comment: As you already guessed, you could do this with a `tabular` environment. Did you already try something?

Comment: @Aesop did the answer suit your requirement

Comment: Yup! Thanks a lot guys!!! Solved it by using packages

Comment: yet I was wondering if there was any possible way to meet the criteria without additional packages. I was using an app called quiver, which is an application that renders latex in latex cells. But I think it actually uses Mathjax to render the Latex Cells and it was kinda tricky for me use to packages... Thank you so much for the thorough answers!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution provided by @Werner is reproduced below  -- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/410766/197451

Two proof environments are provided:

> proofA

and

> proofB

The first uses a regular `tabular`, the second uses a `tabularx` that allows for justified paragraph text.

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcounter{proofstep}
\newcommand{\step}{}
\newenvironment{proofA}
  {\par
   \setcounter{proofstep}{0}%
   \renewcommand{\step}{\refstepcounter{proofstep}\theproofstep. &}%
   \noindent
   \begin{tabular}{ @{} r c l @{}}}
  {\end{tabular}}
\newenvironment{proofB}
  {\par
   \setcounter{proofstep}{0}%
   \renewcommand{\step}{\refstepcounter{proofstep}\theproofstep. &}%
   \noindent
   \tabularx{\textwidth}{ @{} r c X @{} }}
  {\endtabularx}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{ @{} r c l @{} }
  1. & some math & Justification. \\
  2. & some math & Justification.
\end{tabular}

\begin{proofA}
  \step some math & Justification. \\
  \step some math & Justification.
\end{proofA}

\begin{proofB}
  \step some math & This is just another sentence that will span at least two 
   lines. Well, now it will, for sure! \\
  \step some math & Justification.
\end{proofB}

\end{document}
```

The header row can be added by modifying the code for the tabular environment as follows

```
\begin{tabular}{ @{} r c l @{} }
     & \textbf{Step} & \textbf{Reason}\\
  1. & some math     & Justification. \\
  2. & some math     & Justification.
\end{tabular}
```

[image]